# SSMS v18.0 failed when installing

Tags: sql-server, ssms, installation

Previously, I had installed the SSMS v17.9. I uninstalled it and tried to install v18.0 and I have the error 0x80070643. I tried the following:

- Installing the latest .Net Framework 4.8
- Updating Windows 10 and now I have the update from May 2019 (Windows 10 v1903).
- I performed a scan to see if there was a failure in any previous update. Running in cmd (as administrator): **sfc /scannow**

Have anyone of you had the same problem? What can I do to install SSMS v18?

[image]

Comment: What's the log file say that's in the link on the screen?

Comment: This is the log file for the installation:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T7G7a5cRWaJYEaeOLK2qoNG1CzX7l9Zw

Comment: `Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2017` is what failed, and its log is at `C:\Users\Pastor Cortes\AppData\Local\Temp\SsmsSetup\SSMS-Setup-ENU_20190602071436_6_VSTA2017.log`